# Reputation change in leagues page explanation

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

I'm not sure what reputation change (yearly) is. [Mine](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2014-01-01/3040627?sort=reputationchange#3040627) seems huge, especially in comparison with my overall reputation. What is the meaning of this number?

Answer (score 5):

That’s your change in rank. Last year, the reputation you earned that year was the 125,902nd-highest. This year, you’ve earned 968 reputation points, placing you in 6,233rd place.